# Brightness won't work

Tags: display, windows-8.1

My Windows 8.1 Pro Laptop's brightness won't work. I have a Dell Inspiron 5520 that has been Reset before (by me). Don't tell me to update my video driver because I have already. Please help me. Thanks, Joseph

Comment: What do you mean by “brightness won’t work”? Do you mean it is not bright enough? Do you mean you cannot change it?

Comment: Can't change the brightness. Not with Fn+F4 / Fn+F5

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? Have you changed any startup programs? Can you change it before Windows boots? That is, when you turn it on/reboot, you should see a Dell logo or something before you see the Windows logo, try pressing `Pause` several times before you see the Windows logo and see if you can adjust the back-light there. Also, try quickly pressing `F8` several times before the Windows logo to get to the Windows boot menu, then see if you can adjust the brightness there. That way we can determine if it is a hardware issue or a software issue.

Comment: I am on a laptop, no 'Pause'. I also use the OEM logo. @Synetech

Comment: I can do the boot brightness, doesn't help the OS'es brightness.

Comment: Wow, you’re right, there’s [no `Pause`](http://kd.com.pk/new/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/5520-1.jpg) key ([not even](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19285247.aspx) with a `Fn` modifier). It’s not even a netbook. Regardless, if you can adjust the brightness at the boot-menu, then it is a software issue, not a hardware problem (that’s a good thing because software problems are easier and cheaper to fix). What’s likely happening is that your system uses a program/driver to handle the special keys in Windows. Did you uninstall anything or disable and startup programs?

Comment: I don't know of any software. I swipe in from the right of my scratchpad (Charms), I choose settings > Brightness > Change Value...No changes. What do I need to fix?

Comment: I don’t know, I don’t have your laptop, but my system came with some software that detects when I press the brightness and volume keys, so that it can adjust them and display an OSD to show the level. If the program isn’t running, then they don’t work correctly in Windows. I don’t see any obviously corresponding [programs for your system](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/product/inspiron-15r-5520), but you could start with the Touchpad driver; it probably. Did you check the CD/DVD that came with it?

Comment: What all programs do you have installed that change brightness/ hotkey mapping? Flux, Nvidia drivers, Dell Quickset? Personally, my Dell fn keys stop working too sometimes, I wonder if it's related

Comment: I get all of my Dell Drivers off of [Dell Support](http://support.dell.com). **NO WHERE ELSE**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found that I can use the Intel HD Graphics 4000 Control Panel to change the brightness.

**EDIT:**

I reinstalled Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: So tell as how you open it? How do you open Intel HD Graphics 4000 Control Panel?

Comment: I found it under Control Panel > Intel Graphics and Media > Display > Color Enhancement.  YMMV